Hapi.js how to set route options via auth plugin
I need to change route options from auth plugin:
example route
hapiServer.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/users',
            handler: this.handler.getUsersForLoggedInUserCompany.bind(this.handler),
            options: {
                auth: auth.setAuth(hapiServer, {
                    scopes: ['Internal', 'User'],
                    roles: ['userRole'],
                }),
                response: {
                    failAction: 'error',
                    status: {
                        200: AccountSchemas.responseUsers,
                    },
                },
            },
        });

In auth.setAuth I have options based on it and some manipulations to hide sensitive values I have to put in
 auth: auth.setAuth(hapiServer, { scopes: ['Internal', 'User'], roles: ['Rsa.Default'] }),
                plugins: {
                    'hapi-swagger': {
                        'x-vi-visibility': 'external',
                        'x-vi-permission': {
                            scopes: ['Internal', 'User'],
                            roles: ['Rsa.Default'],
                        },
                    },
                },

Is it possible? I tried in auth plugin
  // server.ext('onPostStart', () => {
            //     server.table().forEach((route) => {
            //         // @ts-ignore
            //         route.settings.plugins['hapi-swagger'] = {
            //             // @ts-ignore
            //             ...route.settings.plugins['hapi-swagger'],
            //             'x-vi-visibility': isViVisibility(route.settings.auth || {}),
            //             'x-vi-permission': viPermisions(route.settings.auth || {}),
            //         };
            //     });
            // });

but i can not get information about route in normal way and these values are not passing when I call for /openapi.json route
